# Numpy submatrix operations

Tags: python, numpy, submatrix

I'm looking for an efficient way to perform submatrix operations over a larger matrix without resorting to for loops.

I'm currently doing the operation (for a 3x3 window):

```
newMatrix = numpy.zeros([numRows, numCols])
for i in range(1, numRows-1):
    for j in range(1, numCols-1):
        sub = matrix[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2]
        newMatrix[i][j] = ... #do things with sub matrix
```

This is considerably slower than normal operations with numpy matrices. Is there anything numpy has to offer to solve this, or is that hoping for too much?

Edit:
Specific example

```
xWeight = numpy.array([[-1./8, 0, 1./8], [-2./8, 0, 2./8], [-1./8, 0, 1./8]])
yWeight = numpy.array([[1./8, 2./8, 1./8], [0, 0, 0], [-1./8, -2./8, -1./8]])
```

Inside loop:

```
        dz_dx = numpy.sum(xWeight * sub)
        dz_dy = numpy.sum(yWeight * sub)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do image processing with numpy?

Comment: Is that `matrix` on line 4 supposed to be `newMatrix`?

Comment: What exactly do you do in "do things with sub matrix"? If you do not specify what are you doing, we cannot help you vectorize your code.

Comment: Jim: No, but I imagine there's cross over.   
Brionius: No, that the old matrix the submatrix is extracted from.
Viktor: I intentionally left it vague, because I'm looking for general guidance on this type of problem, of which there are several, not looking for a specific fix. But for example see edits.

Comment: Where do the `dz` elements go? Stackoverflow is really center on discrete examples and specific fixes.

Comment: They're used to solve various further operations that can easily be accomplished with simple numpy operations. This method is what's slowing everything down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you're trying to do a simple convolution?

```
def do(m):
    rows, cols = m.shape
    newMatrix = np.zeros_like(m)
    for i in range(1, rows-1):
        for j in range(1, cols-1):
            sub = matrix[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2]
            newMatrix[i][j] = numpy.sum(xWeight * sub)
    return newMatrix[1:-1, 1:-1]
>>> res1 = do(matrix)
>>> res2 = scipy.signal.convolve2d(matrix, xWeight)[2:-2,2:-2]
>>> np.allclose(np.abs(res1), np.abs(res2))
True
```

Didn't went into details about the sign, but that should hopefully put you on the right track.

Comment: This looks like a neater solution for this specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in numpy.lib.stride_tricks

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
```

In the method:

```
    expansion = stride.as_strided(matrix, shape = (numRows-2, numCols-2, 3, 3), strides = matrix.strides * 2)
    xWeight = numpy.array([[-1./8, 0, 1./8], [-2./8, 0, 2./8], [-1./8, 0, 1./8]])
    yWeight = numpy.array([[1./8, 2./8, 1./8], [0, 0, 0], [-1./8, -2./8, -1./8]])

    dx = xWeight * expansion
    dy = yWeight * expansion

    dx = numpy.sum(numpy.sum(dx, axis=3), axis=2)
    dy = numpy.sum(numpy.sum(dy, axis=3), axis=2)
```

There may well be a better solution, but this is sufficiently simple and general purpose for what I was after. This went through a 1600x1200 matrix in 3.41 seconds, vs 188.47 seconds using for loops.

(Feel free to offer said better solution, if you have it)

Answer (score 2):

Use scipy instead for image processing operations:

http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use `np.ix_`, see this example [from the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

ixgrid = np.ix_([0,1], [2,4])

a[ixgrid]
#array([[2, 4],
#       [7, 9]])
```